# Ethereum Client App (Both Android & IOS)

Tags: ethereum

we want to build native client apps for Ethereum in both Android and IOS. Can you please recommend us what technologies should we use and what should be the architecture of these apps.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS, you can use a 'web3swift' library, fully written in Swift! In the readme, you can find instructions on installation.
https://github.com/matterinc/web3swift

Answer (score 0):

this is still "on the edge". You will need to use the light client.
I am afraid it will be Android only, at least for now.
You can find more here to get started:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mobile-Clients:-Libraries-and-Inproc-Ethereum-Nodes

Best Regards